# jquery .next(); target the next following second or third element

Tags: jquery

We know that the JQuery function of `.next()` will help us find out the next following element
but i want to know that, how we can ask JQuery .next() help us to find out the next's next element or even `next's next's` next element?

I blindly try on `$(this).next().next().val()` and it works, it able to get value of next 2nd element.
so if code like this, `$(this).next().next().next().next().next().val()`
it get 5th element.

I think it should have better way to code it, so does anyone know?

It will be funny if i want to get next 100 element attribute!
so i know you guys will ask what kind of programming or usage need to code like this?.

Comment: check `nextAll` http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/ and `nextUntil` http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ function.

Answer (score 5):

Use your imagination :

```
var elem = ​$("#elementID")​; //gets the start element
elem.siblings().eq(elem.index()+8).css('color', 'red');// ninth next element
```

Start with an element, get all it's siblings and filter with [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) based on the start elements index plus however many sibling elements you wish to skip.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rEWQn/)

Comment: thanks, now i only know there is a function call "eq", will study on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the :eq selector, for example:

```
$(".class").eq(2).css("color", "red");
```

It may be useful to you

Comment: thanks, now i only know there is a function call "eq", will study on it.